# Unable to import ts file from node-modules folder in Angular2

Tags: angular, import, google-places-api, directive

I have installed Google Map places in my Angular 2 project.

```
npm install angular2-google-map-auto-complete
```

[image]

Getting error as cannot find the module:

[image]

Can anybody help me in specifying the path for the same?

Tried with following combinations:

```
../../directives/googleplace.directive
../../../directives/googleplace.directive
../../../../directives/googleplace.directive
../../directives/googleplace.directive
../node-modules/angular2-google-map-auto-complete/directives/googleplace.directive
../../angular2-google-map-auto-complete/directives/googleplace.directive
```

Nothing worked as expected.

Update: I have found the spelling mistake but no luck

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

```
import {GoogleplaceDirective} from '../directives/googleplace.directive';
```

[Please note- its directive**s** with '**s**' in the end.]

and in your component, add directives like this-

```
directives: [GoogleplaceDirective],
```

See if this helps.

---

**EDIT:**

You can use this way-

```
import {GoogleplaceDirective} from '../node_modules/angular2-google-map-auto-complete/directives/googleplace.directive';
```

Verified it in VScode-

[image: VScode screenshot]

---

**EDIT 2:**

**Step1:** copy googleplace.directive.ts file and keep it in your app folder

[image: Folder strcture]

**Step2:** write appcomponent.ts like this-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {GoogleplaceDirective} from './googleplace.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [GoogleplaceDirective],
  template: `<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "address"  (setAddress) = "getAddress($event)" googleplace/>
  `

})
export class AppComponent { 
  public address : Object;
       getAddress(place:Object) {       
           this.address = place['formatted_address'];
           var location = place['geometry']['location'];
           var lat =  location.lat();
           var lng = location.lng();
           console.log("Address Object", place);
       }
}
```

**Step3:** Add script tag in index.html

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

**Output result:**

[image: Output Result]

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for responding but that is not the case. Please check the updated question

Comment: Visual Studio Code

Comment: It worked, can you explain me why it was not taking that part?

Comment: "not taking that part?" which one?

Comment: Also I am getting 404 on console. http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-google-map-auto-complete/directives/googleplace.directive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120567/discussion-between-shoaib-chikate-and-sanket).

Comment: Can you please try to solve this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878023/google-autocompleter-place-doesnt-work-in-the-child-component-in-angular-2