# Google autocompleter place doesn't work in the Child Component in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, google-places-api, angular2-directives

I was using the googleplace directive for the [Google places autocompletor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-google-map-auto-complete).
It works when I use this directive in AppComponent as shown in the link but doesn't work when I used it in the child Components.

**app.routes.ts**

[image]

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig }  from '@angular/router';

import { BaseComponent }  from './components/base/base.component';
import { DashboardComponent }  from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';


const routes: RouterConfig=
    [
        {path:"",redirectTo:"/admin",pathMatch:'full'}, 

        {path:"admin",component:BaseComponent,
            children:[
                    { path: '', component: BaseComponent},
                    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
                ]
         }

    ];


export const appRouterProviders = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

**main.ts**
[image]

```
import {bootstrap}    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {appRouterProviders} from './app.routes';


bootstrap(AppComponent,[appRouterProviders]);
```

**app.component.ts**
[image]

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';


@Component({
    selector : 'my-app',
    template:  `
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        `    ,
        directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

**base.component.ts**
[image]

```
import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,Router }  from '@angular/router';



@Component({
    selector: 'app-base',
    templateUrl:"../app/components/base/base.html",
    directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    precompile:[]

})



export class BaseComponent implements OnInit{

        constructor(private _router:Router){}

        ngOnInit():any{

            this._router.navigate(["admin/dashboard"]);
        }
}
```

**base.html** has `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` has its content

**dashboard.component.ts**
[image]

```
import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import { provideRouter, RouterConfig,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,Router }  from '@angular/router';
import {GoogleplaceDirective} from './../../../directives/googleplace.directive';



@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard',
   template:`
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "address"  (setAddress) = "getAddress($event)" googleplace/>
   `,
    directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,GoogleplaceDirective]
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{

        constructor(private _router:Router){}

        ngOnInit():any{

            // this._router.navigate(["dashboard/business"]);
        }

        public address : Object;
       getAddress(place:Object) {       
           this.address = place['formatted_address'];
           var location = place['geometry']['location'];
           var lat =  location.lat();
           var lng = location.lng();
           console.log("Address Object", place);
       }
}
```

**googleplace.directive**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {NgModel} from '@angular/common';

declare var google:any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[googleplace]',
  providers: [NgModel],
  host: {
    '(input)' : 'onInputChange()'
  }
})
export class GoogleplaceDirective  {
  @Output() setAddress: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  modelValue:any;
  autocomplete:any;
  private _el:HTMLElement;


  constructor(el: ElementRef,private model:NgModel) {
    this._el = el.nativeElement;
    this.modelValue = this.model;
    var input = this._el;
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {});
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.autocomplete, 'place_changed', ()=> {
      var place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
      this.invokeEvent(place);
    });
  }

  invokeEvent(place:Object) {
    this.setAddress.emit(place);
  }


  onInputChange() {
  }
}
```

**index.html**
[image]

**Output:**
[image]

**Update:**

> Found that, it works perfectly when there is one **router-outlet** tag
>   in the project, but fails to work when we have nested router-outlet as
>   above example has nested **router-outlet**

[Github link here](https://github.com/shoaibista/-angular2-google-place-autocomplete-master)

Is there any issue with directive code with child components of a component?
Please let me know how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: @dfsq Code is posted as screenshots. Do you want me to post the text code?

Comment: Can you upload the code into github or plunker?

Comment: @JohnSiu : added link in the question.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate Please check my answer to see if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/AutocompletionService.GetPredictions` require an api key, when you use it inside a router child.

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

Put your google API key in place of API_KEY.

I cannot explain the difference in behavior between child component(no api key needed) and router child(api key required).

According to Google Map Api documentation, API key is required:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

Comment: I want that use case to make it work. I don't want nav bar in app-component. Can you please let me know the reason too?.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate I think I am quite confuse with the intended layout. Do you mean you don't want to use router in app component, and just use base.component as a plain child component of app.component?

Comment: Thank you for all the efforts. But I am not writing routerLinks in app component. Can you please checkout the latest commited code from github link which is mention above in the question and let me know why isn't working in that router navigation structure.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate Fixed. But cannot explain the root cause.

Comment: Sui: Still not working, also added API key. Can you please check the updated Github code.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate What kind of key you use? I just use a new browser key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121045/discussion-between-shoaib-chikate-and-john-siu).

Comment: This worked like charm. really it is one of the weird think which i have observed in my life.Thank you so much